# iOS app cannot read info.plist

Tags: ios, info.plist

I made a copy of my app folder and saved it to another directory on my desktop. Now, my original app (or the copy) cannot run because it says the info.plist cannot be read from:

could not read data from '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/Development/Apps/EUS/EUS Calculator/EUS Calculator/EUS Calculator-Info.plist': The file “EUS Calculator-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

But, the EUS Calculator-Info.plist is at that path. I've looked through SO and the Google and can't seem to find a solution. How can I resolve this?

Comment: For information, where was your app's folder before?

Comment: I never moved it, I simply made a copy. The original is on my Desktop...Desktop/Development/Apps/...I made a copy, pasted that into Desktop/GIT/ and ever since then I have been getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Select your target and then select the Build Settings. In there is a section called "Packaging"

Edit the `Info.plist File` setting. It should be relative to your project file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments

> I never moved it, I simply made a copy. The original is on my Desktop...
>   Desktop/Development/Apps/...I made a copy, pasted that into Desktop/GIT/ and ever since then I have been getting this error

and your error says

```
could not read data from '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/Development/Apps/EUS/EUS Calculator/EUS Calculator/EUS Calculator-Info.plist': 
The file “EUS Calculator-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

so it seems that the info.plist is pointing to the original one.

Comment: Well yes. But I am also working in the original one. When I copied the original file to Desktop/GIT, the original file somehow lost the path to it's info.plist...my bad for not making that clear. I'm not working in the copy. So, I make a copy, paste the copy, in the original everything goes red (all class files, all image file names) and I get the error message saying the app can't find the plist file. I imported everything into a new project and that works fine but I am curious how to resolve this for the future. And also to know what the heck happened.